# The method onFetchComplete(List<Application>) of type MainActivity must override a superclass method error

Tags: android

I am trying to show content from mysql database in listview below is my listactivity which i am implementing to my interface FetchDataListener.But it is giving to errors
1.The method onFetchComplete(List) of type MainActivity must override a superclass method error
2.The method onFetchFailure(List) of type MainActivity must override a superclass method error

Please see below for class and interface files

Class

```
/*package com.example.androidhive;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener{
private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
    initView();  
}

private void initView() {
    // show progress dialog
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    String url = "http://192.168.0.2/android_login_api/include/apps.php";
    FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
    task.execute(url);
}

@Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // create new adapter
    ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    setListAdapter(adapter);       
}

@Override
public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // show failure message
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
}
}
*/
```

Interface

```
/*package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.List;

public interface FetchDataListener {
public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data);

public void onFetchFailure(String msg);
}
*/
```

Please help me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont see where you import the interface in your class

Comment: you mean i need to import interface in my mainactivity?

Comment: yes for example `import com.example.YourClass.FetchDataListener;`

Comment: @tyczj: Not if the interface is in the same package as the implementing class (which it is, from the looks of it).

Comment: @user2723139: What exactly is `Application`? If it's a class you made up yourself, you may want to double check your imports. Android has a built-in `Application` class too (`android.app.Application`), which is probably not what you're after. To avoid further confusion, consider renaming your local class - i.e. prepend it with a project abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLiteDatabase class for this

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Database_Name", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

 //Create Table 
 String  strsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableName(Name  VARCHAR(30),id    INT(15)  unique) ";
db.execSQL(strsql);
```

you can fire query as you do in MYSQL(INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) using db.execSQL()

To Retrive data you can use this

```
 strsql = "SELECT * FROM TableName ";

 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(strsql, null);

    int count = c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (k >= 0) {
              ListviewContent.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name")));
        setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this));
        c.moveToNext();
        k--;

    }

 //you can set retrived data to list view as shown above.
```